# docker RUN/CMD is possibly not executed

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to build a docker file in which I first download and install the Cloud SQL Proxy, before running nodejs.

```
FROM node:13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8000
RUN cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[project-id]:[region]:[instance-id]=tcp:5432 -credential_file=serviceaccount.json &
CMD node index.js
```

When building the docker file, I don't get any errors. Also, the file serviceaccount.json is included and is found.

When running the docker file and checking the logs, I see that the connection in my nodejs app is refused. So there must be a problem with the Cloud SQL proxy. Also, I don't see any output of the Cloud SQL proxy in the logs, only from the nodejs app. When I create a VM and install both packages separately, it works. I get output like "ready for connections".

So somehow, my docker file isn't correct, because the Cloud SQL proxy is not installed or running. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I got it working, but I'm not sure this is the correct way to do.

This is my dockerfile now:

```
FROM node:13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x wrapper.sh
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8000
CMD  ./wrapper.sh
```

And this is my wrapper.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=phosphor-dev-265913:us-central1:dev-sql=tcp:5432 -credential_file=serviceaccount.json &
sleep 5
node index.js
fg %1
```

When I remove the "sleep 5", it does not work because the server is already running before the connection of the cloud_sql_proxy is established. With sleep 5, it works.

Is there any other/better way to wait untill the first command is completely done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RUN` commands are used to do stuff that changes something in the file system of the image like installing packages etc. It is not meant to run a process when the you start a container from the resulting image like you are trying to do. Dockerfile is only used to build a static container image. When you run this image, only the arguments you give to `CMD` instruction(`node index.js`) is executed inside the container.

If you need to run both `cloud_sql_proxy` and `node` inside your container, put them in a shell script and run that shell script as part of `CMD` instruction.

See [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

---

You should ideally have a separate container per process. I'm not sure what `cloud_sql_proxy` does, but probably you can run it in its own container and run your `node` process in its own container and link them using `docker network` if required.

You can use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to manage, start and stop these multiple containers with single command. docker-compose also takes care of setting up the network between the containers automatically. You can also declare that your `node` app depends on `cloud_sql_proxy` container so that docker-compose starts `cloud_sql_proxy` container first and then it starts the `node` app.

Comment: Thank you. I have it (almost). I've edited my question.

Comment: Your node app must be resilient to unavailability of services it depends on. If `cloud_sql_proxy` does not come up before `node` app starts, your node app should retry. Also check if you can separate these processes into two separate containers and use `docker-compose`.

Comment: I understand, but it's for a google cloud project. I need to create a VM template with a docker file, and if necessary, the cloud creates new instances on the fly with the template. I can only add one image to the template, so it should contain everything. It should be self-managed. I cannot use wait (instead of sleep) because cloud_sql_proxy is a process that keeps running. If there is any way to "catch" the response (because the response is "waiting for connections") and then start node index.js, that should be the way to go I think.